# Ideal Time to Load / Mount an external HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, windows-7, external-hdd, ubuntu-studio

This is not exactly a post related to bugs into my machine, but a worrisome behaviour that is happening to my just-bought external HDD.

A few days ago, I created a post on another stack exchange, but it seems that either nobody knows nothing about it or the ones who know did not see that post (laugh):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404582/ideal-time-to-load-mount-an-external-hdd

As I said there, It is taking between 25 and 30 seconds to load and mount it on Linux whereas it is just taking 10 seconds to load on windows and this time is letting me worried about whether it is too long or not.

I made some tests using chronometers and I reached to those numbers.

So, I would like to ask you, guys:

1. has any of you ever made such a test?
2. Is this time too long for you or not?
3. I think it is somehow normal that Linux is taking longer to mount it than on Windows due to the fact its filesystem is NFTS. Do you think the same?
4. How long do you think it is an ideal time to mount an external HDD?

I will seriously be very glad if some of you could let me know your thoughts or opinions about it. Feel free to ask me anything about any technical details or anything about my test or whatever else related to that issue, because it is something that is worrying me so much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a connected HDD, the `mount` command is practically instantaneous, in my experience. At that point, the hardware connection has already been made, so some lower-level handshakes may have taken some time.

Comment: I have a 1.5TB  disk, also NTFS. I just turned it on and it takes about 15 seconds for the icon to appear grayed-out (unmounted) on my desktop. The first time I double-click it to mount, it takes about 10 seconds for the File Manager to open the root of the drive. When I unmount the disk and then mount again, it does in a few seconds. So, I just accepted this normal behavior.

Comment: No surprise Linux would take a longer to detect and mount a partition with a non-native file system. fat32 is faster, but may have to partition larger size drives. A Linux native file system would be best if this availability time is priority, but windows can't even detect many Linux partitions. If it has to stay on NTFS so windows can cope, you may get faster response by adding a udev rule to automatically mount external drive when detected